# Xubuntu login session corrupted?

Tags: xubuntu, login, mouse, xfce, configuration

After one of the innumerable recent updates (in particular to xfce4) I logged out and back in again to find that for one thing the mouse pointer has become invisible and some of the configuration has been lost including the Desktop Background image and the number of virtual screens.  Alternative user logins have not suffered, just the one from which I applied the updates (from the commandline, as root) and attempted the window manager restart as described below.

needrestart indicated that xfce4 could do with a restart.  In an attempt to avoid a full restart I executed "xfwm4 --replace" which did not complete successfully (I do not have the output from that run) so I resorted to a restart from the "Applications" menu.  Following a login to my primary user account, the problems became evident.

It seems that the desktop is not refreshed, as the "Applications" menu appears when clicking the (invisible) mouse pointer on it, though it does not disappear again after another click.

A possible "workaround" might be the adapt the configuration from another user account though it would be rather better to resurrect the absent configuration or at least understand what I can do or avoid doing in future!

This is xubuntu with the following profile:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:printing-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic

$ uname -a
Linux eccentrica 4.18.0-15-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 7 10:56:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks in advance...
    Tigger Wells